# Append an array using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an array with 3 elements(feature) in my code. Currently i have declared them as `$feature = "System","Battery","Signal","Current";`
But in future there can be more features. So I thought of giving an option in my code to add new feature(implemented as GUI) and using `$feature.Add("$new_feature")` command.

This works perfectly for that particular run of the script. But when i run the script again, this new added feature is not appearing. How can i solve this issue, so that when ever new feature is added, then it will remain in the script for ever?

Is this possible?

Comment: You're wanting the data added into one run, also show up as still present in subsequent runs?  Sounds like you need to look into a separate dataset where to keep all of the possible values between each run.  Also, `$feature += $new_feature`

Comment: A script does not remember what happened the last time it ran.  You have to store any data that you want to be available the next time you run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to store the array data in a file:

```
# read array from file
$feature = @(Get-Content 'features.txt')

# write array back to file
$feature | Set-Content 'features.txt'
```

You can use `$PSScriptRoot` to get the location of the script file (so you can store the data file in the same folder). Prior to PowerShell v3 use the following command to determine the folder containing the script:

```
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
```

Another option is to store the data in the registry (easier to locate the data, but a little more complex to handle):

```
$key  = 'HKCU:\some\key'
$name = 'features'

# read array from registry
$feature = @(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $name -EA SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Expand $name)

# create registry value if it didn't exist before
if (-not $?) {
  New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $name -Type MultiString -Value @()
}

# write array back to registry
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $name -Value $feature
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, is there a difference between using `Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent` and 
`Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` as `$PSScriptRoot` in PS2.0 ?

Comment: @sodawillow `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` and `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` are effectively the same (the full path to the script). `Split-Path -Parent` is one way to extract the parent folder from that path.